# Why is my windows message box always choosing you path c++?

Tags: c++, winapi

Here bellow is a program that I'm trying to attach to a window, it works but I wanted the user to have the option to attempt to attach the window without reopening the program. I tried this with a switch statement, but if the process wasn't found and the user opens it then pressed retry why is it repeating the error for when the process isn't open.
The code --

```
class attach 
{
DWORD ProcID;
HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "SONIC HEROES(TM)");
void attempt()
{
    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        const int Window = MessageBoxA(0, "Failed to attach Window!", "Attention", MB_RETRYCANCEL | MB_ICONERROR);
        switch (Window)
        {
        case IDRETRY:
            attempt();
            break;
        case IDCANCEL:
            exit(-1);
            break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBoxA(0, "Window Found!", "Attention", MB_OK | MB_ICONHAND);
    }
}
};
```

Comment: You never change `handle` inside `attempt`

Comment: i don't need to because the handle will only become null if the the process SONIC HEROES(TM).exe isn't opened. and if it isn't opened its then going to ask the user to try to attach it again, but my issue is if it wasn't found the first time and the user then opens it and retry's it will become an unlimited loop of the error  "MessageBoxA(0, "Failed to attach Window!", "Attention", MB_RETRYCANCEL | MB_ICONERROR);"

Comment: Where do you think it will retry? The only time it calls `FindWindowA` is when the class is constructed. Calling `attempt` does not call `FindWindowA` or construct a new object

Comment: So why is it without the case statement it works fine, but if it dosent attach the first time i'll have to re-open the program.

Comment: @Drake Read your code again. `FindWindowA` is called *once* when your class `attach` is constructed. `attempt` **does not** call it again. So if `hwnd` was null, it remains null.

Comment: You can put `FindWindowA` in `attempt()` function.

Comment: i understand where your all getting at, but in the future i'm going to change SONIC HEROES(TM) to a varable so any name can be placed there if a condition is made, but how do i change hwnd not to a null if the proccess then attaches successfully after pressing rerty.btw the hwnd needs to be global or protected for that reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put `FindWindowA` in `attempt()` function and create an array to complete.

Here is a minimal code example:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

CHAR* name = (CHAR*)malloc(1024);

class attach
{
public:     
    void attempt();

private:
    DWORD ProcID;
    HWND hwnd;
};

void attach::attempt()
{      
    hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, name);
    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, name);
        const int Window = MessageBoxA(0, "Failed to attach Window!", "Attention", MB_RETRYCANCEL | MB_ICONERROR);
        switch (Window)
        {
        case IDRETRY:
            attempt();
            break;
        case IDCANCEL:
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBoxA(0, "Window Found!", "Attention", MB_OK | MB_ICONHAND);
        cout << "If you want to attach new process, please input new application name:" << endl;
        cin >> name;
        attempt();
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Input your application name:" << endl;
    cin >> name;
    attach a;
    a.attempt();

    free(name);

    return 0;

}
```